# PHP Multidimensional Array and WS

Tags: php, web-services, web, multidimensional-array, wsdl

Good morning, I'm having the following problem with PHP and WS:

I have a Web Service Server, the client sends me an object of activities. The activities can go from zero to unbounded, each activity has a "Code" and a "Type":

```
 <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Activities" type="tns:activity.CONTENT"/> 

<xs:complexType name="activity.CONTENT">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

When the Web Service client sends me two activities or more I get this from PHP print_r

```
  [Activities] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Type] => NW
                                            [Code] => 001AC001

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Type] => NW
                                            [Code] => 001AC002

                                        )

                                )
```

But when the Web Service client sends me only ONE activity, I get this from PHP print_r()

```
 [Activities] => Array
                                (
                                    [Type] => NW
                                    [Code] => 001AC001

                                )
```

As you can see, in the first case I have a two level array whereas in the second case I have only one level.

I know I can fix this by myself by creating [Activities][0] when there is only one, but I was wondering why this happens, if it is a PHP bug, or I am doing something wrong.

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

What I mean is that if the client sends me only one activity I think I should get:

```
[Activities] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Type] => NW
                                            [Code] => 001AC001

                                        )
                                )
```

Instead of

```
 [Activities] => Array
                                (
                                    [Type] => NW
                                    [Code] => 001AC001

                                )
```

Here this guy has the same problem: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?708197-php-and-WS-array-with-one-row

Maybe we are both doing something wrong.

Comment: Definitely not a PHP bug. It probably has something to do with how you're receiving/handling the array. Can you show us the code before your `print_r()`?

Comment: That is the problem I am not doing anything, just a print_r: function sendActivity($obj) {
 $object=print_r($obj, true);}

Comment: If you want to know what type of response you get (assoc array or multidimensional linear array), you can check if first element exists and is array
`if(isset($yourVar[Activities][0]) && is_array($yourVar[Activities][0])) { //here you have multidimensional array }`

Comment: Yes Sean Doe, you are very right!. But do you have any idea why this happens? it's quite strange

Comment: I had the same issue once with a web-service where the back-end was written in JAVA. Probably because when there is only one item, it sends the item instead of a collection (array in PHP) of items. For some obscure reason they couldn't fix this so I had to go with the same solution proposed by Sean: check if it's an associative (single item) or numeric array (collection of items).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much to all of you. I have a solution to fix the problem, so if no one knows the reason I suppose we will leave it as a mystery :D